# Start Sidekiq automatically if it is not in running state - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redis, sidekiq

I'm using `redis server` and `sidekiq` for my **cron jobs** but some time `sidekiq` kills automatically at backend.

I want to restart `sidekiq` from my controller's action or automatically when it kills down without stoping my rails application server.

Please suggest me how can I manage this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check sidekiq and redis server running or not running by :

```
  def redis_connected?
    !!Sidekiq.redis(&:info) rescue false
  end

  def sidekiq_connected?
    ps = Sidekiq::ProcessSet.new
    ps.size > 0 ? true : false 
  end
```

and you can also start from your controller but this is not a good way because it will start sidekiq but kill rails server.

```
  def start_sidekiq
    system "redis-server &" if !redis_connected?
    system "bundle exec sidekiq -d" if !sidekiq_connected?
    flash[:sidekiq_notification]="Starting server... Please refresh after few seconds"
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

or install and use a server monitoring tool

Comment: Thanks for your answer nitisha it solves my half problem of running sidekiq from my controller but it create a big problem that kills my  rails application :(

Comment: install and use a server monitoring tool

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be your applications responsibility to start external programs.

Install and use a server monitoring tool like [bluepill](https://github.com/bluepill-rb/bluepill) or [god](http://godrb.com/) to ensure all dependencies are up and running.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but if I need to manage from my application how can I handle ? any idea ??

Answer (score 1):

I believe, that this is a wrong way to do it.

I suggest you to setup a monitorring system, which will automatically start your failing workers - you can use [God](http://godrb.com/), [Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) or whatever you like.

However, if you ***realy*** need it, you can perform system calls from ruby - just wrap it in `` or `%x{}` (for example `%x{ bundle exec sidekiq }`)